# Why do my Azure App Service Scale up without my consent?

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-app-service-plans

I have 2 Azure App service plans.  Both are basic B1 tier plans.  They are set to "Manual scale".

Occasionally, I will look at my budget and become very alarmed that they have suddenly moved up to P1V1 plans without my consent and I am now paying over $80 / month for each!

Does anyone know why this might happen when I have them set to manual scale?

Comment: I would open a dialog with Microsoft. I have a few dozen app service plans all set to manual scale and none of them auto scale. You can look at the run history to find the specific dates they were scaled. Screen cap that and send it to them. They will figure it out.

Comment: can you go through the activity logs

Comment: plus, the auto-scaling would anyway only be regarding the number of instances, it would not change the tier of your plan. So yes, you should look through the Activity log and if you do not find anything, contact support.

Comment: After viewing the Activity logs, I was able to confirm that my "Enterprise Application" is responsible (somehow) for auto-scaling up my app services.  Still appears essentially "random" to me, but there must be some explanation.  I plan to open a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: By the way @Andy, when you say "open a dialog with Microsoft", do you mean creating a support request via the Azure Portal by paying the $29/month fee or is there a free alternative?

Comment: @RyanAtwood Open a billing support ticket. That's free.